# getting error - There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DeptId'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting error while clicking create button, i have created 2 tables "Employee" and "Department" and used entity framework.in those tho tables i have data. but while clicking create button getting error in dropdown list

```
employee.cs

     public partial class Employee
        {
            public int EmpId { get; set; }
            public string EmpName { get; set; }
            public string EmpLocation { get; set; }
            public string EmpDesignation { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> DeptId { get; set; }

            public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        }

    department.cs

      public partial class Department
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            public Department()
            {
                this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
            }

            public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
            public string DeptName { get; set; }

            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        }

    EmployeeModel.context.cs

        public partial class EmployeeDBEntities1 : DbContext
        {
            public EmployeeDBEntities1()
                : base("name=EmployeeDBEntities1")
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

            public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        }
```

EmployeeController

```
 public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        EmployeeDBEntities1 db = new EmployeeDBEntities1();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.Employees.ToList());

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(employee);

                }
    }

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeptId, "DeptId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("DeptId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeptId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where do you use the `ViewData`?

Comment: can you show your model you are using here?

Comment: Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a detailed explanation (slightly different error message because of the (awful) use of `DropDownList()` rather than `DropDownListFor()`)